# Avoiding "The number of tasks for this job 100325 exceeds the configured limit" error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a Pig script running on a production cluster weekly.
In the last run I got the following error

```
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 6017: Job failed! Error - Job   initialization failed:
java.io.IOException: The number of tasks for this job 100325 exceeds the configured limit 100000
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.initTasks(JobInProgress.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.initJob(JobTracker.java:4041)
```

I tried to set the mapred.jobtracker.maxtasks.per.job to 100000 in the Pig Properties but with no luck.

Any idea on how to limit my job to create less than 100000 mappers?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try fiddling around with the split size system properties, by setting `mapred.min.split.size` to something quite large you should end up with less mappers.  Now if you have 100325 files you'll need to use `CombineFileInputFormat`.